# How to select all elements but the current one in a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, graph, nodes, overlap

I am in a situation where i want to process at each interation of a for loop the current element with others element in the loop but not the current element itself, and that in order to check the intersection of the element with others.
More specifically i implement a graph where each `node` is associated with an `ArrayList<Set<Integer>>`.

What i have done so far is the following :

```
 for (ArrayList<Set<Integer>> ds : allArrays) {
        
        numberOfOverlaps = 0;
        allArraysCopy = allArrays;
        allArraysCopy.remove(ds);
     
        if (itNodes.hasNext())
             currentNode = itNodes.next();
       
        for (ArrayList<Set<Integer>> otherDs : allArraysCopy){
            if (arraySetIntersect(ds,otherDs)) {
                numberOfOverlaps++;
                neighborsOverlaps.put(numberOfOverlaps,currentNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

In my code i set the index of the nodes to be associated with those of the arrays of set : e.g the first array of set `ds` is associated with the first node.

In order to check other intersections in the for loop is the line `allArraysCopy.remove(ds);` of good approach ?
Thanks.

Comment: This looks like its overly complicated. What about using a classic for loop with an index and instead remember to not check against that index. _But_ for me the big question is why do need to loop over the whole array again in the inner loop, right now you are checking if `a` intersects `b` but also if `b` intersects `a` so I wonder if this double check is really needed? If not then you would only need to check forward in the inner loop from the current index to the end

Comment: if `b` intersects `a` is another iteration where i need to evaluate the `numberOfOverlaps` of the current node being processed by the loop, but could you elaborate your proposition ?

Comment: Ok, then skip that part of my comment but use an old style for loop

Comment: Please elaborate how to no check against the current index in the loop.

Comment: `if (outerIndex == innerIndex) { continue; }`

Comment: also is it acceptable to use `currentNode = itNodes.next();` for the next iteration of `ds` knowing that each `ds` is associated with the node having the same index like i did ? otherwise i would have done it differently by altering the structure of a node and adding `ds` inside the node.